# How to enable and disable a table rows and columns on specific time?

Tags: jquery

I have made a table in which the columns are updated from the user's selection of items from another table. But i want that the table which is updating needs to be disabled for further entries of selected items when certain level of number of items is reached. How can i do?

```
 <table border="1" class="table1" >
 <tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="name">Mango</td><td class="value">100</td>>/tr>
 <tr><td class="name">Orange</td><td class="value">150</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="name">Apple</td><td class="value">200</td></tr>
 </table>

 <table border="1" class="table2" >
 <tr><td>Name</td><td>Value</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="text">
 </td><td class="value"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><span class="items">0</span>Items | Total</td><td class="total">
 0</td></tr></table>
```

i want when items are selected from first table, the second table is updated with item name and its value.. there should be increment on the text of class items and the value of the item should also be added on the total class... But the user is only allowed to choose two items from first table. So when two items are selected , i want the columns of second table should be disabled so that it will not take more entries from first table. Pl Help.

```
 if ($('.items').html() == "2" ){
 $(".table2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

I have tried this code for disabling the table but is not working.

Comment: How does one select items in the first table? There does not seem to be any method of doing so (check boxes, script, etc.). Do you have any script code you can show us so that we can help you?

Comment: just image there is a input checkbox with every item. on checking the checkbox, the item is updated onto the second table..... i have not made script yet because i'm not getting the right logic for coding

Comment: Can you show us what you already have or tried in javascript?

Comment: everything is going well but just the disabling part is not working for the table.... i have updated this post for the disabling code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by disabling the list of selected items.  Could you just hide the first list when the max has been chosen?  I am using divs for clarity here.

```
<div id="mango" class="name">Mango</div>
<div id="orange" class="name">Orange</div>
<div id="apple" class="name">Apple</div>

<div class="text"></div>
<div class="value"></div>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
 var count = 0;
        $(".name").click(function() {

var fruit = $(this).attr('id');


   $('.text').append("" + fruit + "");
    $('#counter').html(count);

  count++; 
            if(count > 1) {
                $('.name').hide();
            }

        })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toL33fzy/4/

Comment: by disabling i mean to say that i want to make the second table to prevent further updation of items when a certain value of items are selected from the first table.

Comment: But would that not usually be done by disabling, or hiding, or whatever, the first table, so that no more items can be selected in the first place?  Try the fiddle, see if it suits your needs.